# Not able to integrate TFS 2015 with SonarQube

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Currently I'm trying to integrate TFS 2015 with SonarQube but with no result, the situation is that no where it is mentionned how to update the build agent to take the SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner into consideration. 
When i started integrating the two systems, the error was that the c# sonar plugin version is not compatible with the SonarQube runner so decided to override all files contained in the Build agent for sonarqube prebuild 
C:***\Agent\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.35\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1 which make it work but i'm not sure if this is the right way how to it should work.

**Additional Information:**

TFS version: TFS 2015 update 4.1

SonarQube Version: 6.7.3

SonarQube C# plugin version: 7.0.1.4822

MSbuild Version: 15.0

MSBuild SonarQube Scanner: 4.2.0.1214-net46

**Edit:**
Just to let you know, i didn't update the agent, I'm using the same one that was used before installing the Sonarqube.

Comment: If you are using the new TFS/VSTS (i.e. non-XAML) build system you shouldn't be updating the SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner directly. Instead, install the latest version of the SonarQube VSTS extension from the VSTS marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube).

Comment: I already did but with no luck, once installed it shows only SonarQube as option in services tab from collection configuration panel, am i missing something?

Comment: The services tab is about configuring external endpoints. You want to "manage extensions" - click on the shopping bag icon in the top right hand corner (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018).
The _SonarQubePreBuild_ task is definitely not in the latest version - the newest tasks are now named _SonarQubePrepare_, _SonarQubeAnalyze_ and _SonarQubePublish_.
You'll need to install the new version of the extension, then edit your build definitions to use the new tasks.

Comment: Please provide more information to your question so that is is easier to help you

Comment: @duncanp, i already installed the extension, but nothing has changed in the build steps, did i need to restart the tfs server ?

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang what information do you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compatibility issue. Actually the error message already indicated that as you mentioned "`c# sonar plugin version is not compatible with the SonarQube runner`".

Just check the [SonarQube Extension for VSTS/TFS Compatibility](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeExtensionforVSTS-TFS-Compatibility) and [Compatibility with the SonarQube C# plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Compatibility)

> Versions 3.x are compatible with:
>
> - TFS 2015 Update 3
> - TFS 2017 Update 1
> - VSTS
>
> Versions 4.x are compatible with:
>
> - TFS 2017 Update 2+
> - TFS 2018
> - VSTS
>
> **Note:** *if you are running on TFS **earlier than 2017 Update 2, you will need to download and manually install the latest 3.x version of
>   the VSIX**. You can download the VSIX on the "[Releases](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-vsts/releases)" page of
>   the GitHub repository You can browse the documentation on [SonarQube
>   Extension 3.0](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/SonarQube+Extension+3.0)*

[image]

So, in your scenario (**TFS 2015 Update4.1**) you need to follow instructions available on the ["SonarQube Extension 3.0" documentation page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/SonarQube+Extension+3.0).

Below article for your reference :

[INTEGRATE SONARQUBE IN YOUR TFS OR VSTS BUILD](https://writeabout.net/2016/04/26/integrate-sonarqube-in-your-tfs-or-vsts-build/)

---

**UPDATE:**

It's still the compatibility issue, based on this [Plugin Version Matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix)  `SonarQube Version: 6.7.3` is not compatible with  `c# plugin 6.6`, it's compatible with `C# plugin 7.1`.

In your scenario I suggest you downgrading to `SonarQube server v6.x` with  `c# plugin 6.6` as you have to install the `"SonarQube Extension 3.0"` to support TFS 2015.

Comment: I already followed those steps also but with no luck, do i need to add the sonarqube scanner as a capability to the agent?

Comment: @Yazid No need to do that, Just make sure everything matches the compatibility. e.g. if you installed "`SonarQube Extension 3.0`", you need to install the `SonarQube C# plugin version 4.5 -6.6`

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer, i've downgraded the sonarqube c# plugin to 6.6 version
The C# plugin installed on the SonarQube server is not compatible with the SonarQube analysis agent (i.e. the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe, or the build automation task)

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the agent because it use an old version:

C:\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.35\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml

So i think 1.0.35 is the version which is not mentioned in the compatibility matrix

Comment: @Yazid It's still the compatibility issue, based on this [Plugin Version Matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix)  `SonarQube Version: 6.7.3 ` is not compatible with  `c# plugin 6.6 `, it's compatible with `C# plugin 7.1`. In your scenario I suggest you downgrading to `SonarQube server v6.x` with  `c# plugin 6.6 ` as you have to install the `"SonarQube Extension 3.0"` to support TFS 2015.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, i contacted the administrator to downgrade the sonarqube server and then i will check if it is working correctly. Just one question, is the change that i've made to get the agent working can be considered as solution to get the code checked by sonarqube, because i can get analysis and recommendation about the changes that need be done

Comment: Just to let you know, sonarc# is working for me with SonarQube Version 6.7.3

Comment: yes sir it can be considered as answer. Just to let you know if the problem persist then update sonarqube files in the tfs agent with the version compatibe of msbuild sonnar scanner