# sonarqube 8.9.2 with tfs 2015 build integration - is it posible?

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, tfs-2015

I'm using sonarqube 8.9.2 and TFS2015 update 4.

in 8.9.2 there is no c# plugin as it's built-in.

when trying to run the sonarqube step of the build I get an error saying the SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip is missing.

##[error]Could not find a file on the SonarQube server. Url: http://XXXXXXXXXX/static/csharp/SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip

2021-09-02T14:34:22.7202456Z ##[error]Failed to update the SonarQube MSBuild Runner binaries. Check the server url, verify that the C# plugin is correctly installed on the SonarQube server and that the SonarQube server has been restarted.

2021-09-02T14:34:22.7202456Z ##[error]Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1

2021-09-02T14:34:22.7360027Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1

the only thing I can find in the configuration is the Azure DevOps configuration in the ALM section but I'm using a local TFS 2015.
I've seen this post and the relevant answer but in 8.9 there is no C# plugin - [Not able to integrate TFS 2015 with SonarQube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156820/not-able-to-integrate-tfs-2015-with-sonarqube)

is it possible to integrate?

p.s,
I tried working with an older version of sonarqube (7.9.X) only to find there are issues with compatibility.
I installed v9 only to find that there is a bug in the latest releases and it will not start.

getting sick of this and starting to think I need to build a script that will run it manually.

thanks for your help,
Shay

Comment: AFAIK, I am afraid it it impossible to integrate sonarqube 8.9.2 with tfs 2015.

Comment: damm... well ill start looking into a script that runs SQ "manually" and add it to the build flow.